# Object composition in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

How does object composition work in Solidity? I haven't found a comprehensive guide, and all examples seem to deal with hello world level stuff or ERC20 token implementations.

1. Can I have a contract with public properties which are other contracts?
2. Can these contract instances passed as function arguments between contracts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and Yes

```
contract Foo {
    function Foo() {}

    function chop() public returns (bytes32)
    {
        return "Chop!!!";
    }
}

contract Bar {
    // Foo bytecode will be compiled into Bar's bytecode
    Foo public foo = new Foo(); 

    // Foo bytecode will be loaded into memory from an existing Foo deployment
    Foo public foo2 = Foo(0xF00BAA...); 

    // An address primitive to cast;
    address public hoo;

    // Internal calls can pass complex types
    function kungFoo(Foo sumFoo) internal {
        sumFoo.chop();
    }

    // External calls ca pass basic types
    function kungHoo(address sumHoo) public {
        hoo = sumHoo;
        Foo(hoo).chop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but assuming a Foo (complex instance type) can't be passed in externally? There wouldn't be much need for it in any case